# Simple PHP code is not working. Whats the reason?

Tags: php

Just to understand how PHP works in some situations: Why this code is not working?

```
<?php
class MyCustomClass {
?>
<?php
  function hello_world() {
    return "Hello World";
  }
}
?>
```

Error: `syntax error, unexpected '?>', expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST) in...`

Is it not allowed to close and reopen php tags? Otherwise I see no issues here.

Comment: You break the class definition.

Comment: @AD7six Hehe, complicated  The user can write own methods from his backend with a PHP Syntax Highlighter. But the highlighting is not working if there is no php tag included in the editor. So I tried to close the php tag in the class so that the user can open it in his editor. :-)

Comment: Basically the answer is that I cannot break a class by closing and reopen a php tag. With this in mind, I need to search for another way 

Comment: **There are multiple possible causes of failure and insecure code in what you want to achieve.** However, ignoring these, you started with an incorrect design. The code that you let the user edit and the final code that you want to assemble this way are different things; they do not need to stay together in the source code. You can keep the class skeleton in a file and the editable fragments in different files or in the database. Assemble the class using the skeleton and the fragments and write it in the final code file. Never attempt to read and parse the final file, just regenerate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can NOT break up a class definition into multiple files. You also can NOT break a class definition into multiple PHP blocks, unless the break is within a method declaration. The following will not work:

```
<?php
class MyCustomClass {
?>
<?php
  function hello_world() {
    return "Hello World";
  }
}
```

However, the following is allowed:

```
<?php
class MyCustomClass {

  function hello_world() {
      ?> whatever you want here <?php
      return "Hello World";
  }
}
```